# Xml data retrieve to database

Tags: php, mysql, xml, database

i have made a php file to retrive data to a database from a xml file:

```
foreach ($xml -> track as $row) {
        $title = $row ->name;
        $artist = $row ->artist-> name;
        $duration = $row ->duration;
        $image = $row ->album ->image;
```

and my question is: from this xml, how can i get the second image(medium), as from my code it only gets the first(small). Thank you.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCQsd.png

Comment: do you use simplexml ?

Comment: yes @splash58   please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

find image tag with attribute size equal medium

```
foreach ($row->album->image as $im)
  if ($im['size'] == 'medium') echo $image = $im;
```

Answer (score 0):

When parsing a XML file, multiple nodes with the same name will share the same array in the same order.

So, to get other images here :

```
$image_small      = $row->album->image[0];
$image_medium     = $row->album->image[1];
$image_large      = $row->album->image[2];
$image_extralarge = $row->album->image[3];
```

Comment: if order will never change

Comment: Thank you @steve Chamaillard but splash reply first, but this will work also.

Comment: His answer is way better as order can change indeed.